# Falsely judged not 'Designed for tablets' list in the Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, android-resources

Recently I uploaded my new app to Google Play Store. Then the optimization tips says:

> **Design your app for tablets**
>
> **Your Production APK needs to meet the following criteria:**
>
> (X) Your APK should include custom drawables assets for common tablet
>   screen densities.

But indeed I include multiple drawable assets for a variety of screen densities (-mdpi, -tvdpi, -hdpi, -xhdpi, -xxhdpi and -xxxhdpi).

The only reason I can imagine for this is that I have these drawables not in **drawable** folders but in **mipmap** ones.

For my app doesn't use any drawables beside of the **ic_launcher** icons in **mipmap** folders, It has no **drawable-***dpi** folders.

However, Google themself recommend to use **mipmap** holders instead of **drawable** ones.

[Managing Launcher Icons as mipmap Resources](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/projects/index.html#mipmap):

> it is still best practice to move your launcher icons to the mipmap/
>   folders

Only I had followed their guide. Then I got the above tip from developer console.

Is this a bug of Google Play Store, isn't it? Or, are there any solution for this?

Comment: It is best practice to keep the launcher icons inside of mipmap folder. The mipmap folder is only for Launcher Icons.  If you are going to use any other icons inside the app including your icon, you should create multiple sizes within the drawables folder. mipmap formats the icons differently than drawables. Not sure if that answers your question.  Is the icons formatted incorrectly as the icon, or within the app?

Comment: @EugeneH All of drawables my app has are ic_launchers. It is quite a simple app. Still I can prepare dummy drawables and place them to drawable-***dpi folders only for getting rid of the tip...

Comment: @CommonsWare I have no drawables other than ic_launchers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last, it was solved.

If you have only vector-drawables (except for the ic_launchers in the mipmaps), perhaps the GooglePlay console detects it automatically as *not include any drawables assets for common tablet screen densities*.

Few days ago, I found that there is the **[Design for Tablet Contact Form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/tabletq)** on the GooglePlay console site. So, after I claimed that my app had only vector-drawable assets, a human staff responded to me and he said my app was actually ready for tablet. Now, it became all right.

[image]